# problem when building a code under qgis 2.8 c++ api

Tags: qgis, feature-class

i have this code

```
QgsUniqueValueRenderer *lRenderer = (QgsUniqueValueRenderer *)pLayer->renderer();

QMap<QString, QgsSymbol*> lSymbolMap = lRenderer->symbolMap();

QgsSymbol *lSymbol = lSymbolMap.value("");
```

My problem is that in the c++ qgis api the header QgsUniqueValueRenderer has been deleted

can i subsitute QgsUniqueValueRenderer by qgsrendererV2 ?